# Is there any way to convert a Rc<T> into an Arc<T>?

Tags: concurrency, rust

I have a graph node:

```
pub struct GraphNode<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    pub f: GraphLikeFunc<T>,
    pub m: String,
    pub children: Vec<Rc<GraphNode<T>>>,
    id: Uuid,
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to:

```
pub struct ConcurrentGraphNode<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    pub f: GraphLikeFunc<T>,
    pub m: String,
    pub children: Vec<Arc<ConcurrentGraphNode<T>>>,
    id: Uuid,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do such a thing without rebuilding the whole graph. The main difference between `Rc` and `Arc` is that [`Rc` does not implement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-Send) `Send` and `Sync` while [`Arc` does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-Send).

Those guarantees are checked at compile-time, so there is no way to switch directly between those two at runtime: you have to consume your `GraphNode` to build a `ConcurrentGraphNode` from scratch.